# Converting object to List<object>

Tags: c#, list, object

I've looked at similar questions but nothing quite fits. I have an object which happens to contain a List. I'd like to get it into something I can enumerate.

For example:

```
object listObject;          // contains a List<Something>
List<object> list;

list = listObject as List<object>;   // list contains null after

foreach ( object o in list )
{
    // do stuff
}
```

The conversion from object to List<object> is the problem.

**EDIT:**

What I finished with:

```
object listObject;          // contains a List<Something>
List<object> list;

IEnumerable enumerable = listObject as IEnumerable;

if ( enumerable != null )
{
    list = enumerable.Cast<object>().ToList();

    foreach ( object o in list )
    {
         // do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try This:

```
list = (listObject as IEnumerable).Cast<object>().ToList()
```

Comment: The expression `(listObject as IEnumerable).Cast<object>()` will throw a `NullReferenceException` if `listObject` is cannot be cast to `IEnumerable`. The expression `((IEnumerable)listObject).Cast<object>()` provides a slightly more informative exception if `listObject` is non-null and does not implement `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @Corey - I was just waiting the required 10 minutes to Accept.

Comment: @280Z28 - I understand At this point in my code, I'm guaranteed that it'll be a List of something.

Comment: @BillP3rd Sorry.  I see a lot of good elegant answers that never get credited is all :)